# Matlab libraries in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, codec, libraries, matlab

I just installed matlab on my computer, seemingly successfully, but I've been trying to run a program, and I'm getting the following error:

```
>> reproduceResults
Warning: Directory already exists. 
> In reproduceResults at 14 
Processing ./data/baby.mp4
Error using VideoReader/init (line 429)
The file requires the following codec(s) to be installed on your system:
    video/x-h264


Error in VideoReader (line 132)
            obj.init(fileName);

Error in amplify_spatial_lpyr_temporal_iir (line 31)
    vid = VideoReader(vidFile);

Error in reproduceResults (line 20)
amplify_spatial_lpyr_temporal_iir(inFile, resultsDir, 10, 16, 0.4, 0.05, 0.1);

>>
```

For reference, the code that I'm trying to run is here:
http://people.csail.mit.edu/mrub/vidmag/#code

I'm running reproduceResults.m, after downloading all of the video files that they provided.

Any help would be appreciated!

---

I can't find any answers on google that work. The one that I've tried is this:
http://memyselfandcomputer.blogspot.com/2011/01/matlab-2010-videox-h264-error-on-ubuntu.html

It doesn't seem to change anything though. Is there a way to get a more verbose output to help me debug/search better?

Comment: I'm asked to log in when I click the last link in your post, by the way, so I don't know what you've tried already, but have you tried installing the `x264` package? It might be named something slightly different in Ubuntu, but run `apt-cache search x264` and I can try to advise you.

Answer (score 4):

A little late but I also ran into the same issue. One fix is to install the codecs via `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get -y install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-multiverse
```

This fixed it for me.

Comment: I had to remove the last package: `sudo apt-get -y install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly`
`

Comment: I had success on a [Matlab Amazon EC2 instance](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00F009JDY) with even fewer packages: `sudo apt-get -y install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad  gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly`

Comment: This should be marked as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is a thread that suggests multiple solutions, hopefully it contains the right one for you: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=775943

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
```

Add this ppa for gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg on 14.04, had the same problem and fixed for me now.

Comment: I'd note that it looks like those repositories are specific to 14.04 (which this question pre-dates). I'm also curious to what this offers over the default repos

Comment: For 14.04, this ppa is needed to install `gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg` - the package in the default repo cannot currently be installed on 14.04.